# I don't understand how this inherence works

Tags: python

Just a heads up, i'm quite new to python and while learning. my tutorial book told me to create the following script: https://pastebin.com/cLWUuJnv (long script in paste bin). But the following lines make no sense to me, hoping someone could explain:

> `next_scene_name = current_scene.enter()` (line 18)

`" and

```
> next_scene_name = current_scene.enter() (line 23)
```

Both seem to use the same concept but i don't understand it.

Comment: What exactly do you not understand about these lines?

Comment: How does it work with the enter function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This whole line is a variable assignment.
`next_scene_name` is set to the value of `current_scene.enter()`
`current_scene` is another variable, specifically a object of some kind.
The `.` represents attribute access. `enter` is the name of the attribute, in this case a method (a function that is also a attribute), and the parentheses are a function call. 
All together the line is getting to get the `enter` method from `current_scene` call it an set `next_scene_name` equal to the return value of the function call.

Comment: so if im correct: if my current_scene = Death. 'print Death.quips[randint(0, len(self.quips)-1)]' would be ran?

Comment: Yes, if `current_scene` is an instance of `Death` then that line will run.

Answer (score 0):

`current_scene` is some sort of object -- perhaps a class or a module.  (I haven't looked at the pastebin, so I don't know for sure what type of object it is.  But for this example it doesn't really matter.)

It contains a function named `enter().`

Those lines of code call the function and assign the result to a variable named `next_scene_name`.